# Cleaning no clean flux paste

Tags: soldering

I am using [no-clean flux paste](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00425FUW2) for assembling the PCB board. Although it is 'no-clean', I need to clean it. Can anyone please suggest on cleaning the 'no-clean' flux? What do I need? And how to clean?

Answer (score 2):

From [the manufacturer](http://www.mgchemicals.com/tech-support/instructional-guides/flux-removal/):

> **Q. How do I remove flux?**
>
> A. Removing flux is a two-step process. The first step is dissolving the flux. The second step is rinsing the dissolved flux off of the PC board. The rinsing step is very important because after dissolving the flux it may appear that the solids in the flux have disappeared, but once the flux remover has evaporated away, the solids will re-deposit on the board as white residue.
>
> **Step 1 : Dissolving the Flux**
>
> If you are using flux remover in aerosol form, spray a little flux remover onto the flux, then agitate with a hog hair cleaning brush. If you are using our 4140 Flux Remover, you may spray it liberally, as it is safe on your components. If you are using 413B Heavy Duty Flux remover, you may spray it liberally on the solder side of the board, but be careful to only apply it directly to the flux contaminated area if you are using it on the component side of the board, as it will harm some components. The 4140 is plastic safe so it may be applied liberally. Have a can of 413B handy in case you run into a patch of burnt-on difficult to remove flux. If you are using flux remover in liquid form, pour the flux remover into a tray. If you are using 4140 Flux Remover, you may then submerge the PC board into the tray, agitating the flux with a hog-hair brush. If you are using 413B Heavy Duty Flux Remover, you should not submerge the board into the tray, as the components will be damaged. Instead, wet the hog-hair brush you are using by dipping it into the tray, then use it to agitate the flux on the board. Periodically rinse and re-wet the brush by swishing it in the flux remover
>
> **Step 2 : Rinsing the board**
>
> You must ensure that you push the dissolved flux solids off of the board, before the flux remover evaporates and the solids re-deposit. If you are using flux remover in aerosol form, the easiest way to do this is to hold the board vertically and liberally apply more flux remover until you see the flux remover running off of the board. If you have dissolved the flux by submerging the board in liquid flux remover, just dip the board into the tray and swish the flux remover and you should be ok. If you have been using the particular tray to dissolve flux on a number of boards, dissolved flux may accumulate in the tray and dipping the board may actually deposit flux solids onto the board. In this case you will want to either set up a separate tray for rinsing, or have an aerosol can handy for rinsing. A particularly good option for rinsing dissolved flux off of a board is to use our 406B Super Wash. Super Wash comes in a large aerosol can, allowing for liberal use, and it dries very rapidly. Super Wash will rinse off un-evaporated flux remover as well as flux solids, and almost immediately after rinsing your board with it the board will be dry and ready for service.